# Show inline keyboard after pressing on inline button

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

If I create an inline keyboard markup with a button, is it possible to show another inline keyboard by pressing on that button? I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: This question is too open-ended. It is difficult to help you without asking a specific question about an existing implimentation.

Comment: No, I just want to know If it's possible to do that.  Like how you press a button then some text shows up. Can an inline keyboard show up by pressing the inline button? @CmdCoder858

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with [`editMessageReplyMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup).